# Leaflet map contextmenu position

Tags: leaflet

In leaflet map, on mouse right click, context menu is display right side to the cursor on map. Now our application is made compatible with right to left layout (for arabic). We need to display the context menu left side to the cursor now. We are using "leaft-contextmenu". Is there any simple way to achieve this?